# Recover MySQL Database from raw data files [XAMPP | MySQL | InnoDB]

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, innodb, recovery

Okay, So my PC was starting to run a bit sluggish so I reset windows, keeping my files. Because my brain wasn't turned on I forgot to make a backup of my MySQL DB beforehand. I still have all of the raw files, so I still actually have the database but so far have found no way to get it back into the new XAMPP/MySQL installation.

This is what is in my (OLD) ../xampp/mysql/ folder:

[image: Screenshot of file explorer showing mysql folder]

If any of you awesome people could help me get the raw files back into the MySQL DB, I would be beyond appreciative.

Comment: try to rename the `data` folder in the new `xampp/mysql` to `data1`, and copy the `data` folder from the old `xampp/mysql` to the new one.

Comment: Okay I think that is getting me somewhere. The problem I have no is it is trying to auto login with the "root" user, and the root user had a password on the old one. Basically I need to disable the auto login function now

Comment: @coderodour With your advice I managed to work it out. I done as you said, and after going to PHPMyAdmin's config.inc.php and changing the auth_type to cookie I was able to get in. Thank you so much buddy

Comment: glad to help, I will repost my comment as an answer so this post can be useful in the future to others. Would really appreciate if you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename the `data` folder in the new `xampp/mysql` to something else like `data1` or `data_backup`, and copy the `data` folder from the old `xampp/mysql` to the new one to replace the one you renamed above.

**NOTE:** Please refer to Michael Longhurst's, the OP's comment above in case you had a password on the previous installation.

Comment: The following video gives demonstration:

https://i.gyazo.com/cfea94105dc04c8b5699e1a0cbdf36c8.mp4